# SSH config file + shell script help

Tags: shell-script, ssh

Well, what I want to do seems a bit convoluted but its the only way I can think of to get the result I want.

So here goes.

I want to automate ssh to my Pi, in the following fashion:

1. My Pi boots up and auto-starts 4 separate instances of screen running bfgminer.
2. Have a shell script on my laptop to ssh into the Pi and open 4 terminals. 1 per screen instance. So I can monitor them all AND control the terminals. I have looked into tmux, but at this point I'm lost.

So I'm thinking something along these lines:

1. Pi boots and runs 4 screen instances named USB0, USB1, USB2, USB3 (This is already completed)
2. On my laptop, open terminal and start my shell script. Something like this:

   ```
   gnome-terminal -e <ssh into pi and open 'screen -d -r USB0'>
   gnome-terminal -e <ssh into pi and open 'screen -d -r USB1'>
   gnome-terminal -e <ssh into pi and open 'screen -d -r USB2'>
   gnome-terminal -e <ssh into pi and open 'screen -d -r USB3'>
   ```
3. This will then open 4 terminal windows each automatically connecting to a separate screen instance.

I think this is possible with ssh config file. But I don't know how to do it. I know it should be possible to get ssh to auto login with username and password, and make it call up screen.

Maybe have ssh autologin and run a script on the pi to begin screen?

I have tried using screen's split screen but its not what I want. And tmux scares me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For passwordless connections with ssh you need to :

1. use ssh-keygen to generate your public key.
2. use ssh-copy-id to copy the public key to the remote machine.